# Strange migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, migration

I have got a strange migration problem in Rails.

I have got this user table

- password
- email
- ...

I want to extend this user table with few new columns like

- name
- dob
- ..

Then I want to run a migration like this to fill the new columns for my first 2 users:

```
class UpdateUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    User.find(1).update_attributes!( :name => 'Alexander', :dob => '1984-08-20')

    User.find(2).update_attributes!( :name => 'Ben', :dob => '1929-04-04')
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

Here's the problem: When I run all migration files (rake db:migrate) WITHOUT the last one (UpdateUser) and afterwards run a new migration (rake db:migrate) WITH the last one it works. But it doesn't work when I'm doing all migrations in one step (drop, create and migrate).

So I have to exclude the last migration-file and include it after the first "migration-round" again... why is that?

Comment: Perhaps you could include the error stack trace so that we can better understand your issue?

Comment: When I run rake db:migrate --trace there is no error.

Comment: Are you actually creating `user` id 1 and 2 in some earlier migration?

Comment: Yes I did, otherwise it would never work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you just update your tables when you add the columns. Therefore you have to execute the `User.reset_column_information` method after adding the columns to ensure, that your model has the current column informations.

```
add_column ...

User.reset_column_information

User.find(1).update_attributes!( :name => 'Alexander', :dob => '1984-08-20')
User.find(2).update_attributes!( :name => 'Ben', :dob => '1929-04-04')
```

You can find more informations about the ActiveRecord Migration at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html